# Accessing a server from sp_addlinkedserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just successfully added another server using the following:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='serverA'

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'serverA', 'false', NULL, 'user', 'password'
```

Now I would like to access a database that is on "serverA"

I tried doing a simple query but struck out:

```
Select top 5 * from sys.serverA <--Did not work (intellisense did not recognize it either)

Select top 5 * from severA <--Did not work (intellisense did not recognize it either)
```

How can I access the databases that are on serverA? I'm sure it is just a matter of syntax, but I did not see anything under sys. that indicated it would access the other databases.

Comment: Intellisense in SSMS don't suggests all possible objects for the user, however, exists many others products that do [this](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/features.html#linkedserver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to actually specify database and table. There're not top 5 rows on server, only in specific tables:

```
select top 5 * from serverA.<your database>.<schema name>.<table name>
```

You can find more info [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize I had to include the ".dbo" as well.